# Shift Bootstrap Checkboxes to horizontal rather than stacked

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Pardon my novice as I am just a beginner. I am looking to move the following checkboxes that display vertically on my website to be aligned side by side rather than stacked on top of one another. I know I have them in a row div, but the checkboxes behave the same way out of them. Anyways here is the following code that applies to this question. If any advice could be spared it would be greatly appreciated.

```
 <div class="form-check">
      <input
        class="form-check-input"
        type="checkbox"
        value
        id="flexCheckChecked"
        checked
      />Half Day
      <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked"></label>
    </div>
    <div>
      Travel
      <div class="form-check">
        <input
          class="form-check-input"
          type="checkbox"
          value
          id="flexCheckChecked"
          checked
        />None
        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked"></label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input
          class="form-check-input"
          type="checkbox"
          value
          id="flexCheckChecked"
          checked
        />One Way
        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked"></label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input
          class="form-check-input"
          type="checkbox"
          value
          id="flexCheckChecked"
          checked
        />Round Trip
        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked"></label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input
          class="form-check-input"
          type="checkbox"
          value
          id="flexCheckChecked"
          checked
        />Round Trip
        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked"></label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
```

Comment: Don't wrap them in divs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't even need to wrap them in a `row`/`col`. Bootstrap has inbuilt support for horizontally stacked checkboxes ([Inline Checkboxes Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/checks-radios/#inline)).

1. Don't wrap your checkboxes in another `div`.
2. Change `form-check` to `form-check form-check-inline`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    Travel
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value id="flexCheckChecked" checked />None
      <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value id="flexCheckChecked" checked />One Way
      <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value id="flexCheckChecked" checked />Round Trip
      <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value id="flexCheckChecked" checked />Round Trip
      <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value id="flexCheckChecked" checked>Half Day
    <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked"></label>
</div>

<div>
    Travel
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value id="flexCheckChecked" checked>None
            <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked"></label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value id="flexCheckChecked" checked>One Way
            <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked"></label>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col">
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value id="flexCheckChecked" checked>Round Trip
            <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked"></label>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col">
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value id="flexCheckChecked" checked>Round Trip
            <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked"></label>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```